# CreateWrappedSurface() failed for a dataprovider-backed CGImageRef

Tags: ios, swift2, core-image

I'm following a iOS 9 development book in the section of Core Image. I ran into an issue when applying a filter to an UIImage.

The following code is taken from the book:

```
resultHandler: { (image: UIImage?, info: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Void in
            if let image = image, var ciImage = CIImage(image: image) where SLComposeViewController.isAvailableForServiceType(SLServiceTypeTwitter) {
                ciImage = ciImage.imageByApplyingFilter("CIPixellate", withInputParameters: ["inputScale" : 10.0])
                let ciContext = CIContext(options: nil)
                let cgImage = ciContext.createCGImage(ciImage, fromRect: ciImage.extent)
                let tweetImage = UIImage(CGImage: cgImage)
                let tweetVC = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter)
                tweetVC.setInitialText("Here's a photo I tweeted. #pragsios9")
                tweetVC.addImage(tweetImage)
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                    self.presentViewController(tweetVC, animated: true, completion: nil) })
                }
        })
```

The code builds and runs but when I hit that resultHandler, the following log is printed out:

```
CreateWrappedSurface() failed for a dataprovider-backed CGImageRef.
```

and the image is not pixellated.

Followed the book step by step and at this point, simply copied and pasted that code.

**Update**

Tracking it down a bit, it seems that `CIImage(image: image)` is failing. I'm using the first image from the sample images from the simulator.

I managed to get a different image which actually gets pixellated but still getting that log message.

Answer (score 0):

Invoking CGImage reference seems to get rid of the message:
var ciImage = CIImage(CGImage: image.CGImage)